# Firebase billing: Do extra daily reads roll over? Do free reads get used first?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase spark allows a project to have 50K firestore reads a day. We are planning on moving to the blaze plan, because we expect to exceed that limit on high traffic days. My question is how these extra reads work. It's $0.06 per 100K documents, but are these daily? What I am asking is that if I use 50K of my free reads halfway through the day, and then I am incurred a charge of 6 cents to read more, do I get to continue using these reads the next day if I only used a couple of these, or will I get charged 6 cents again if I run through the daily 50K and need more reads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't pay 6 cents to get 100K reads after your initial free tier quota.  You pay 6/100K cents per read (that is to say, 6 divided by 100K, a **very** tiny amount per read).  Stating it in terms of 100K reads is just easier to reason about than dealing with extremely tiny numbers.